# order of arrival of message on a mailboxprocessor

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

Is there /How can I get guarantee on the order of arrival for the messages sent to a mailboxprocessor

That is, on a thread if I do

```
agent.post(msg1)
agent.post(msg2)
```

How can I be sure that, in the treatment loop for the agent, the messages will be received in order ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are.  The implementation of `Post` is as you might guess, it just adds an item to the queue (on the current thread, under a lock), and posts work to notify any waiting agent to wake up and process it.  So if you call `Post` twice on the same thread, one after another, the messages get into the queue in that order.

Comment: I need to investigate further then. Because I add disordered elements in my concurrent queue where I stored the data in upon reception. I add a problem for the last message which is none, signaling the end right after posting a non last message. I just added a bool to the other message saying if they are last or not.

Comment: I was spanning a new thread for each message received in order to not block the writing since my reading is done from a blocking collection in the same code. bad idea, as I loose control over the ordering !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `inbox.Scan(function _ -> None // return an Option)` to find the messages if you have some way of detecting order. Of course, this comes at a price to performance, so leaving the queue alone is the best idea.